# Retrieving variable in array in session object PHP

Tags: php, session

I want to access one of the @_SESSION objects, retrieve a protected array and access the array information.

Heres the object:

```
object(Zend\Stdlib\ArrayObject)[271]
 protected 'storage' => 
      array (size=1)
          'session' => string 'example@hotmail.com 0' (length=18)
 protected 'flag' => int 2
 protected 'iteratorClass' => string 'ArrayIterator' (length=13)
 protected 'protectedProperties' => 
     array (size=4)
        0 => string 'storage' (length=7)
        1 => string 'flag' (length=4)
        2 => string 'iteratorClass' (length=13)
        3 => string 'protectedProperties' (length=19)
```

I was able to access the session object like this:

```
$_SESSION['Zend_Auth']
```

But when i tried to retrieve the the information like this:

```
$_SESSION['Zend_Auth']->storage['session']
```

It returns null. 
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: _"retrieve a protected array"_ You can't do that from outside the object -- that's what it means to be protected.

Comment: That said, there's probably a method on the object that will give you what you're looking for, something like `getSession()` or `getStorage()` ...

Comment: I didnt notice that before posting the question, stupid mistake.
I actually went to the zend/stdlib/ArrayObject Class and changed the storage to public.
It works now but its a kinda of lame fix since its not appropriate to change that Class.

Comment: you should perhaps add zend (framework) to the title and the tags as the session object here is not a session object, but there is an object from Zend framework *in* the session. Just saying, as PHP has no session object (in it's own session library).

Comment: @Alex Howansky: Protected is access outside the object, you might have meant private which is on *that* object only (but not that instance only).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access a protected member, you need to access it from within the same type (sub-type), see [visibility (PHP Docs)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php).

```
class SessionReader extends \Zend\Stdlib\ArrayObject
{
    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function access(\Zend\Stdlib\ArrayObject $auth) {
        return $auth->storage;
    }
}

$reader = new SessionReader();
$storage = $reader->access($_SESSION['Zend_Auth']);
$session = $storage['session'];
```

This is a generic example, it works with every protected member.

In your case, the **`Zend\Stdlib\ArrayObject`** there might be additional ways to access that member (or data inside that member), in [that case](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-stdlib/blob/master/src/ArrayObject.php) :

```
$session = $_SESSION['Zend_Auth']->getArrayCopy()['session'];

// or

$session = $_SESSION['Zend_Auth']['session']; // via ArrayAccess
```

Accessing this way is implementation specific.

Comment: Your awesome! Exactly what i was looking for :)